# How do I get the return of a result from a Win or loss in Rock paper scissors javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return

How would I update the game score after each result? This is something i've been working on in console as part of a school project and spent way too much time trying to tie this up. I have managed to get the results to show on the console as who is the winner based on the switch and cases but how do I take that extracted outcome of string text and make something that will update the game array? Sorry if i'm not asking the right question

```
const game = {
  win: 0,
  loss: 0,
};

const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

var random1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
var random2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

var bot1 = choices[random1];
var bot2 = choices[random2];

console.log("Player 1:" + bot1);
console.log("Player 2:" + bot2);

var result = "";

function returnResult() {
  switch (bot1) {
    case "paper":
      switch (bot2) {
        case "rock":
          console.log("Player 1 Wins!");
          result = win++;
          break;
        case "scissors":
          console.log("Player 2 Wins!");
          result = loss++;
          break;
        case "paper":
          console.log("Draw!");
          break;
      }
  }

  switch (bot1) {
    case "rock":
      switch (bot2) {
        case "scissors":
          console.log("Player 1 Wins!");
          result = win++;
          break;
        case "paper":
          console.log("Player 2 Wins!");
          result = loss++;
          break;
        case "rock":
          console.log("Draw!");
          break;
      }
  }

  switch (bot1) {
    case "scissors":
      switch (bot2) {
        case "paper":
          console.log("Player 1 Wins!");
          result = win++;
          break;
        case "rock":
          console.log("Player 2 Wins!");
          result = loss++;
          break;
        case "scissors":
          console.log("Draw!");
          break;
      }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: where is win and loss defined?

Comment: at the top, no?

Comment: wouldn't that be game.win or game.loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you intend on playing the game, but here is a suggestion on how to keep score in your `game` object.  Press the Play button to start game and keep  score in `game`:

```js
const game = {
  win: 0,
  loss: 0,
};

const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

function returnResult() {
  console.clear() // This is just to prevent console crowding for this example

  // Move your random number generators inside the function
  // so you get a new random number each time game is played.
  const random1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
  const random2 = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

  const bot1 = choices[random1];
  const bot2 = choices[random2];

  console.log("Player 1:" + bot1);
  console.log("Player 2:" + bot2);

  // var result = "";  You don't this if you are keeping score in `game` object

  // No need to call switch on bot1 three times:
  switch (bot1) {
    case "paper":
      switch (bot2) {
        case "rock":
          console.log("Player 1 Wins!");
          game.win++;  // Update game win
          break;
        case "scissors":
          console.log("Player 2 Wins!");
          game.loss++; // Update game loss
          break;
        case "paper":
          console.log("Draw!");
          break;
      }
      break;

    case "rock":
      switch (bot2) {
        case "scissors":
          console.log("Player 1 Wins!");
          game.win++; // Update game win
          break;
        case "paper":
          console.log("Player 2 Wins!");
          game.loss++; // Update game loss
          break;
        case "rock":
          console.log("Draw!");
          break;
      }
      break;

    case "scissors":
      switch (bot2) {
        case "paper":
          console.log("Player 1 Wins!");
          game.win++; // Update game win
          break;
        case "rock":
          console.log("Player 2 Wins!");
          game.loss++; // Update game loss
          break;
        case "scissors":
          console.log("Draw!");
          break;
      }
      break;
  }

  // return result;  No need to return result.  Update game object every play instead.
  console.log(game)
  return game // Return game object if needed
}
```

```html
<button onclick="returnResult()">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, didnt work for me, I have to show the results in the console so I cannot use a click button.  these were the steps of the homework I need to follow 
9) Create a variable named "results" and set its value equal to an empty string

10) Write an if statement to check if the win property is greater than 0. If true the code block...
a) ...should append the value of the bot1 variable to the results variable
b) append the string " beats " to the results variable

11) Write an else if statement to check if the loss property is greater than 0. If true the code block...

Comment: Thanks Tim, I see how your solution works now! there wouldn't be anyway to keep the result to only appear on the console view on the website? Much appreciated